# ksoap2-android licensing in commertial application

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am planning to use ksoap2-android in my android application. I am worried about the licensing part. Will I be able to use it in commertial applications? The licensing details provided by ksoap2 is not very clear. If anybody has used it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently MIT License: **The MIT License is a free software license originating at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT). It is a permissive free software license, meaning that it permits reuse within proprietary software provided all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice.**

You can find the license information here: https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/